# How to pass a ‘do not crawl’ list to scrapy that is not regex based?

Tags: python, scrapy

Is there some way to pass scrapy a list of URLs to not crawl?

I found the `LinkExtractor` class, which has a `deny` parameter, but it’s regex based. I just want to pass it a list of URLs.

Background: I have a scrapy crawler based on the SitemapSpider class that can extract and index all the links from an XML sitemap no problem.

Since I am using it to index sites on a daily basis (it’s crawling job postings), I only want it to look at new pages. It saves server burden and index time for me to not look at previously indexed pages.

I’ve tried passing a list of links that I’ve previously indexed, but I get an error that the list of links are not regex objects. It could be that I just don’t know how to convert url strings to regex objects.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the shortest code necessary to replicate the issue.

Comment: Can do once I’m back at my computer. 

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string to a regular expression that matches *only* that string, use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape any regex metacharacters, then [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) to compile the resulting string into a regex.

```
import re

url_list = ['http://example.com/', 'http://example.net/']
deny_list = [re.compile(re.escape(url)) for url in url_list]
```

---

As a side note, this may or may not help for your use case, but if you know the list of denied URLs in advance (i.e. when writing your program), then you can use an external tool to compile them directly to an efficient regex. I'm particularly fond of [`regexp-opt`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegexpOpt), which is built-in to Emacs.

For instance, if we know in advance that we want to block those two URLs above (example.com and example.net), then we can do this in Emacs

```
(regexp-opt '("http://example.com/" "http://example.net"))
```

which gives us this

```
\(?:http://example\.\(?:com/\|net\)\)
```

and that's a much more efficient regex than checking the two URLs separately. But this only works if you know the URLs in advance, as I don't offhand know of any Python tool to precompile match lists like this. (I'm sure one exists, I just don't know of it offhand)

Answer (score 0):

Option #1

The link extractor also has a `process_value` parameter that can be set to a callable that can be used to filter certain urls by returning `None` if the extracted url is in your list of urls, otherwise it can simply return the url unchanged.

[docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml)

Example:

```
previously_indexed = [....] # list of urls

def link_filter(value):
    if value in previously_indexed:
        return None
    return value

linkextractor = LinkExtractor(..., process_value=link_filter)
```

Option #2

Since you are using the sitemap spider you can override the spiders `sitemap_filter` method to filter the urls that have been previously indexed.

[docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.SitemapSpider.sitemap_filter)

for example:

```
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider

class FilteredSitemapSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'filtered_sitemap_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    sitemap_urls = ['http://example.com/sitemap.xml']
    previously_indexed = [....]

    def sitemap_filter(self, entries):
        for entry in entries:
            if entry['loc'] not in previously_indexed:
                yield entry
```